# Adding elements to a div using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a todo list with React and found out that we use states in react unlike `innerHTML` or `appendChild()` in Javascript.

Here's where I'm facing the problem:
When a user clicks a Button, a simple todo is added to the parent Div, and I mean '**Added** not **Replaced**.

However, when using react hooks `useState()`, It's just replacing the element, but I want to **Add** it to the div. Here's the code:

```
export default function TodoContainer() {

let [item, setItem] = useState('Nothing to show...');

function handleClick() {
    setItem(item += <TodoItems/>)
}
return (

    <div className="wholeContainer">
        <div className="tododiv">
            <span className="todos">Todos: </span>
            <hr/>
            {item}
        </div>
        <button className="add" onClick={handleClick}>
        <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
            Add a Todo
        </button>
    </div>
);
```

}

So, when using `setItem(item + <TodoItem/>)`, it just shows : [object Object]

Please help me, I don't know almost nothing about react as I just recently started learning it.
**By the way, the `<TodoItems/>` returns a div with a todo and its detail inside of it.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you `item += <TodoItems/>` you are appending a JSX literal to a (*possibly*) string, and the result seems to be interpreted as a Javascript object. Objects are not valid JSX and renderable.

You may want an array of todos for the state, and when adding a new todo add only the data, not the JSX. When adding a todo to the array you need to create a new array reference and shallow copy the previous state. You'll map the state to JSX in the render return.

Example:

```
export default function TodoContainer() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  function handleClick() {
    setTodos(todos => [...todos, "new todo"]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="wholeContainer">
      <div className="tododiv">
        <span className="todos">Todos: </span>
        <hr/>
        {todos.length
          ? todos.map(todo => <TodoItems key={todo} todo={todo} />)
          : 'Nothing to show...'
        }
        </div>
        <button className="add" onClick={handleClick}>
          <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
          Add a Todo
        </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: So, I should first create an array of todos and then use that to display it using something like a for loop?

Comment: @M.Abdullah Yes. Store only the data in state. An array is a great data structure for storing a list of todos. You will iterate the data structure to map the data to what you want to render.

Comment: I'm trying to add todos inside the array using: "setTodos(todos => [...todos, "new todo"]);" But the problem is, right away when I try to console.log the array to look if it's added or not, the array is empty. And when I add another todo, it only shows the previous one. Can u help me with this?

Comment: @M.Abdullah This is because React state updates are asynchronously processed, logging the state immediately after enqueueing the update only logs the state from the current render cycle, not what you are updating it to. Use a `useEffect` hook to log out state updates, i.e. `useEffect(() => console.log(todos), [todos]);`.